# Delphi XE2 and TeeChart 9

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

i download TeeChart Pro v2012 Evaluation, i'm working with Delphi XE2.
I run the demo exe i found with the product, and i tried to reproduce the code about Gantt charts, more precisely the part to drag and drop the element of the Gantt.
I got the following error: "TGanttTool is not declared"
I was unable to find this object anywhere in the code, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me here.
Simplifying the Mouse dragging example to the maximum, creating everything at runtime, here it is the minimum code to have a Gantt dragging example. Does it work for you?

```
uses VCLTee.Chart, VCLTee.GanttCh, VCLTee.TeeGanttTool;

var Chart1 : TChart;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1:=TChart.Create(Self);
  Chart1.Parent:=Self;
  Chart1.Align:=alClient;

  Chart1.View3D:=False;
  Chart1.Zoom.Allow:=False;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TGanttSeries) as TGanttSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues(5);
    Marks.Visible:=True;
  end;

  (Chart1.Tools.Add(TGanttTool) as TGanttTool).Series:=Chart1[0];
end;
```

Maybe the problem is just in the paths in your IDE. Please check there aren't wrong references present in the library/search path. And check the correct ones (referencing TeeChart) are ont he top of the lists.

Comment: It is ok now! I start my computer this morning, and test it, no problem at all, i can drag! But i discover another issue, the date on the X-axis and the date of the object when i drag it are not synchronized at all!
The first date, on the X-axis, is 01/01/2013 but the Gantt object to display this date must be outside the wall!
Again referencing to the example:

  Lbl1.Caption:= 'Date de début: ' + DateTimeToStr(Sender.Gantt.StartValues[GanttBar])+
                 ' - Date de fin: ' + DateTimeToStr(Sender.Gantt.EndValues[GanttBar]);

Comment: Please, open a new question adding the according code to reproduce the problem and explaining it with detail

Comment: We supposed to buy the pro version, until that i'm back to the version inculded in XE2.
I will re-check it when it will be actual again.
Tnx